# Jquery animate scrollTop not smooth (Parralax Effect)

Tags: jquery, animation, responsive-design

I have been asked to create a website, and the animation needs to work the same as what is shown on the link http://www.piperdesign.co.uk/clients/sanctum/demo2/sanctum_HEX.html

I have pretty much done this, but the problem is the animation is not smooth enough.

Here is the link where I have already created the animation http://rapidzdev.co.uk/sanctum/

The code below is what I have done already.

```
$('#main-menu ul li').on('click','a',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var link = $(this).attr('href');
   var title = $(this).html().replace(' ','-').toLowerCase();
   var scroll = $('#'+title).offset().top;
   $('body').stop().animate({'scrollTop':scroll},'slow', 'easeOutCirc');
   return false;
})
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any animation on that website (because I blocked flash ;]) can you please explain the animation? [You shouldn't be using personal links anyway](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

try this and update your jquery.

$('body').stop().animate({'scrollTop':scroll}, 600);

Answer (score 0):

To get smoother animations do not use jQuery. You are animating a big image and an expensive propriety: background-position.

You should try this to make things smoother:

- Use CSS animations or requestTimeFrame instead of jQuery
- Animate top or translate propriety instead on background-position
- Minimize reflows by making your image element absolute positioned